# Wrap all elements from class="foo" up until class="bar"

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I have a whole load of DOM, which contains div's which have classes "foo" followed somewhere down the line by "bar", like this...

```
<div class="kev">...</div>
<div class="foo">...</div>
<div class="bob">...</div>
<div class="tom">...</div>
<div class="bar">...</div>
<div class="pat">...</div>
<div class="foo">
    <div class="tim">...</div>
    <div class="foo">...</div>
    <div class="jim">...</div>
    <div class="bar">...</div>
    <div class="rob">...</div>
</div>
<div class="meg">...</div>
<div class="bar">...</div>
```

and I want it to wrap all classes starting with "foo" and ending with "bar", like this...

```
<div class="kev">...</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="foo">...</div>
    <div class="bob">...</div>
    <div class="tom">...</div>
    <div class="bar">...</div>
</div><!--end of wrapper-->
<div class="pat">...</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="tim">...</div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="foo">...</div>
                <div class="jim">...</div>
                <div class="bar">...</div>
            </div><!--end of wrapper-->
        <div class="rob">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="meg">...</div>
    <div class="bar">...</div>
</div><!--end of wrapper-->
```

note: they could be nested, as above.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Post the code you have so far and the errors you have with it.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
$(".foo").each(function () {
     $(this).nextUntil(".bar + *").addBack().wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'/>");
});
```

Comment: Nice thankyou, works a charm. Looks strange tho... addBack().next().addBack()

Comment: Yes it's because nextUntil() doesn't include ".bar" so I need to do next() then addBack().

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each($(".foo"), function() {
            var untilBar = $(this).nextUntil(".bar").addBack(); //Select .foo div and it's siblings until .bar
            untilBar.add(untilBar.next()).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>'); //Add .bar to the set and wrap
        });
```

See this fiddle please: http://jsfiddle.net/BYxHL/